# Gradient of complex scalar field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I want to calculate the gradient of

$$ w^H H F (F^H F)^{-1} F^H H^H w $$

with respect to $ F $, which is complex.

I am basing on this previous answer [Derivative of Nested Matrix Quadratic Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656408/derivative-of-nested-matrix-quadratic-form) that uses differentials to compute the derivative of a similar expression with real matrices. However, I have difficulties in computing the differential when $ (.)^H $ is involved.

For instance, I make these changes: $ x = F^H H^H w $ and $ Z = F^H F $. Then, I obtain $ dx = 0 $ and $ dZ = F^H dF $.

Is it correct that $ dx = 0 $ or should I consider approaching the problem from a different perspective? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
x &= F^HH^Hw &\implies x^H = w^HHF \cr
Z &= F^HF    &\implies Z^{-1}F^H = F^+ {\rm \,\,(pseudoinverse)}\cr
}$$
and yes, in the context of Wirtinger derivatives $\,dx=0$.

Write the function in terms of these new variables. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= x^HZ^{-1}x \cr
d\phi
 &= dx^HZ^{-1}x + x^HdZ^{-1}x \cr
 &= dx^HZ^{-1}x - x^HZ^{-1}dZ\,Z^{-1}x \cr
 &= (w^HH\,dF)Z^{-1}x - x^HZ^{-1}(F^HdF)\,Z^{-1}x \cr
 &= \Big(Z^{-1}xw^HH - Z^{-1}xx^HZ^{-1}F^H\Big)^T:dF \cr
 &= \Big(Z^{-1}F^HH^Hww^HH - Z^{-1}F^HH^Hww^HHFZ^{-1}F^H\Big)^T:dF \cr
 &= \Big(F^+H^Hww^HH - F^+H^Hww^HHFF^+\Big)^T:dF \cr
 &= \Big((F^+H^Hww^HH)\,(I - FF^+)\Big)^T:dF \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial F} &= (I - FF^+)^T (F^+H^Hww^HH)^T \cr
}$$
where a colon was used in some steps as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Thank you greg!