# Derivative of Quadratic Form with Mixed Kronecker Product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, gradient-descent

I need to compute the derivative of

$$ (m^T \otimes a^H) [(m^* \otimes I)(m^T \otimes I)]^{-1} (m^* \otimes a) $$

with respect to $ m $, which is a complex-valued vector. Moreover, $ a $ is also a complex vector and $ I $ is the identity matrix. Finally, $ (\cdot)^T, (\cdot)^H, (\cdot)^* $ denote the transpose, Hermitian transpose, and conjugate, respectively.

There exists a similar question in [Derivative of Nested Matrix Quadratic Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656408/derivative-of-nested-matrix-quadratic-form) that uses differentials. However, the Kronecker product complicates my derivation.

Comment: Let $M=m^*m^T\,$ and note that
$$\eqalign{
\Big((m^*\otimes I)(m^T\otimes I)\Big)^{-1}
 = \Big(M\otimes I\Big)^{-1}  = M^{-1}\otimes I
}$$
The problem is $M$ is a rank-one matrix and has no inverse.

Comment: I see @greg! Thank you for pointing out this aspect.